# Bind data from C# to Javascript for Adobe Illustrator scripting

Tags: javascript, c#, adobe-illustrator

I'm creating a new C# desktop app connect to Adobe Illustrator by using Javascript scripting. 
I want to bind variable from C# to Javascript but I don't know how to do that.
Anybody can help me?

I have tried to use `<%=variable%>` but not work.

```
Illustrator.Application app = new Illustrator.Application();
string templatePath = @"D:\data\template.ai";
string csUsername= "CSharp Username"
app.Open(templatePath);
app.DoJavaScript("var jsUsername= 'Javascript Username'" +
                "var myDocument = app.documents[0]; " +
                "myDocument.layers[0].locked = false;" +
                "var myTextFrame = myDocument.textFrames.add(); " +
                "myTextFrame.position = [5, 5]; " +
                "myTextFrame.contents = jsUsername");
```

I want to bind csUsername to jsUsername variable.

Comment: you can insert the json encoded value into the JavaScript.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? I'm a new to C#

Answer (score 0):

You can string-build the javascript!
Look at this following way to make the string:
`string MyJsString = "var userName = '" + csUsername + "'; alert(userName);";`